Dealing with mold on AC unit
My internal AC unit is located in the garage and I'm starting to get worried about the amount of mold growing on the unit. It usually comes in the summer when the condensation on the unit is bad but this is abnormal.
I'm going to try spraying vinegar on it, but should I be concerned about this long term? Should I hire someone to replace the white part? It feels like plaster and softens when the condensation is bad. For added context, I don't see and signs of mold in my vents or in the attic.
I appreciate any help.

try bleach spray

use pressure washer

Some photos would help us see what "the white part" is...
